# Searching for non "on-hold" questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

### Explanation

I know this issue has been addressed before, however right now I seek to create a temporary solution for myself to solve it - the [on-hold] questions. Just searching through recent questions I can immediately see, say, half of them are [on hold] This is really annoying, as usually I have no real reason to cast a reopen vote.

### Question

So, tl;dr I need a way to search for questions that aren't [on hold]. Is this something that exists and my google/stackexchange meta searches are simply futile? If not, I would like to request this feature be added to stackexchange.

Comment: Do you want to *just* filter out on-hold status, or closed status too?

Comment: @ArtOfCode Well, I suppose having flexibility is great. Both is good...

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to filter out both "on hold" and "closed" questions, you can use the `closed:no` search term:

https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ano will give you a list of currently open questions.

Comment: Incidentally, if you type in any search, you will see an '**[Advanced Search Tips](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?)**' link next to the search bar.